# Why is JdbcTemplate null in my JUnit test?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, junit

I have a test сlass with a method where I add some data to the database and then retrieve it and check if the data is the same:

```
public class QueryImplTest {
    @Autowired
    Jdbc jdbcTemplate;
    
    QueryImpl queryImpl = new QueryImpl(jdbcTemplate);
    
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
    SomeObject someExpectedObject = new SomeObject(//object 
    queryImpl.saveSomeObject(someExpectedObject)
    SomeObject someRealObject = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SELECT_OBJECT_QUERY, SomeObject.Class)
    //all of the Assertions

}
```

And I get a `Cannot invoke JdbcTemplate.update()(from saveSomeObject method) because this.jdbcTemplate is null`

The QueryImpl class:

```
@Repository
public class QueryImpl {
    
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    public QueryImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
    //methods and query strings

}
```

Comment: For `QueryImpl` try to autowire `JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate` as constructor parameter instead of field on. Than in  `QueryImplTest ` you can init queryImpl by providing `jdbcTemplate` as parameter: `QueryImpl queryImpl = new QueryImpl(jdbcTemplate);`

Comment: @artiomi, I tried that now, didn't work, got the same mistake

Comment: Your unit test doesn't seem to be managed by Spring, so `@AutoWired` **does nothing**, in addition, even if it were managed, it would be set **after** `new QueryImpl(jdbcTemplate)` was already executed.

Comment: You're right, I had no @Runner annotation

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are Autowiring ***Jdbc*** class in the test case. That is incorrect. Please use ***JdbcTemplate*** class. Here is the fixed version of your test case.

```java
@JdbcTest
public class QueryImplTest {
    
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    QueryImpl queryImpl = new QueryImpl();
    
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
    SomeObject someExpectedObject = new SomeObject(//object 
    queryImpl.saveSomeObject(someExpectedObject)
    SomeObject someRealObject = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SELECT_OBJECT_QUERY, SomeObject.Class)
    //all of the Assertions

}
```

If you need more details please read this article.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-testing

Comment: I've added that annotation, didn't work

Comment: You are getting the same error or error is different this time? I am assuming you are using Spring Boot Framework.

Comment: Yes, this is Spring Boot and the same error

Comment: Is Datasource configured in the test case?

Comment: Yes, with application.properties

Comment: Please use setter method to set jdcb template instance in test case. I believe this fix the issue.       
QueryImpl queryImpl = new QueryImpl(); queryImpl.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work, same error

Comment: That is strange. It should work. Can you please share the recent test code?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my original post

Comment: I've edited my original post

Comment: Thanks, Can you please move QueryImpl queryImpl = new QueryImpl(jdbcTemplate); in the "@Before annotated method" and also fix the Jdbc with JdbcTemplate. Use "@JdbcTest annotation on class level"

Comment: what do you mean by "fix the Jdbc with JdbcTemplate"?

Comment: In test case you are autowiring Jdbc class. It should be JdbcTemplate

Comment: Didn't work, i've deleted the @Autowired annotation

Comment: Are you still facing the issue or it is resolved?

Comment: Resolved, the problem was with the class not having a @RunWith() annotation